# Wrong Date value between java and angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, date

I created a rest service to return a date.

I use Java on the back end and AngularJS on the front end.

My code in java is something like this:

```java
   SimpleDateFormat myFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date myDate = myFormat.parse("1900-01-01 12:00:00");
   return myDate;
```

And when I get this value from the service I display it on the front end with this code:

```
 <div>
    <h4>{{myDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</h4>
 </div>
```

The page shows "1899-12-31 23:56:16".

I tried again but with the current date and it shows normally in the system.

Comment: Smells like a timezone representation problem.  Which timezones are the client and the server in?

Comment: The both timezones are GMT:-5, but the error no happen always, sometimes show a correct hour

Comment: This is your back-end? Skip the HTML/AngularJS part for now, and trace through the Java code. This Question is not appropriate to Stack Overflow, with not enough information and no specific programming question.

Comment: What is the information that you need? i wrote the problem, my problem is a put a date in java and after i get a different date in angular, the question is: Why i get a different date? or Why this date has a different interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with all the january 1st dates from 1900 to 2020, and, in fact, Java and javascript apparently return **different milliseconds values** in certain intervals (in fact, only the dates between 1912-1940 coincide).

I've tested empirically that this somehow random difference is caused by the **lack of an specific Time Zone** when parsing the date string in Java (in the javascript part, the reference used is implicitly UTC, I guess). Moreover, it is always a good practice to specify a TimeZone when parsing dates.

So I recommend you add the timezone specifier for UTC (or GMT+0000) in your java program:

```
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    Date myDate=myFormat.parse("1900-01-01 12:00:00 +0000");
```

I insist that, in my guess, the AngularJS scriptlet is referencing from UTC, no matter which time zone the client is actually in.